# PDF of cosine of a uniform random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

There is a formula for the density of the cosine of a random variable that's uniform on (0,3),
its density function is as follows:

$$
f_X(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3 \pi}&~\text{ if } x \in (0, 3π)\\
 0&\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Also let $Y =\cos (X)$, where the transformation $g (·) =\cos (·)$ is the cosine function.

I suppose that it needs to be monotone firstly in order to solve it. Maybe by creating partitions from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and so on? Could someone help me derive it?

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the interval $(0;3\pi)$ in 3 monotonic intervals

$(0;\pi) \cup [\pi;2\pi) \cup [2\pi;3\pi)$

and then reasoning as usual obtaining

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$

$y \in (-1;1)$

This is a good [Reputable Source](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_1_3_functions_continuous_var.php) (theorem 4.2)

Answer (score 0):

$F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=\begin{cases}0,&y\le -1\\P(\cos X\le y),&-1<y<1\\1,&y\ge 1\end{cases}$

For $|y|<1,\\P(\cos X\le y)=P((2\pi-\arccos y\ge X\ge\arccos y)\vee(3\pi>X\ge2\pi+\arccos y))\\=\frac1{3\pi}[(2\pi-\arccos y)-\arccos y]+\frac1{3\pi}[3\pi-(2\pi+\arccos y)]\\=1-\frac1\pi\arccos y$

Now just differentiate $F_Y(y)$ to get PDF of $Y$.